# how to get updated app hosted in localhost

Tags: android

In my project I suppose to host my inventory.apk in my localhost of my network. This app will periodically checks whether new version inventory.apk is uploaded. If a new version of inventory.apk is found, I want to ask the clients of that company to update the old version of inventory.apk in their device. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in my opinion the easiest way to check new .apk files is to name .apk files with the dates. For example: 27_11_2014.apk .

If you follow this path, then you can get the name/names of apk files in your directory by this kind of code:

```
URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
```

You can use SharedPreferences to keep first initialization date and compare it with parsed .apk file name. If the file name has a newer date you can prompt a dialog to warn user about update.

There is only one thing that you cannot achieve without root permission, and that is automatically updating the app itself. Not sure if you were aiming this kind of usage but wanted to warn you, apps cannot update themselves without root permission.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is very helpful, is there any library that I can use to update the app without having root permission. If not I have to prompt app installation activity of android os after latest download is completed, if user touch install I think the previous version will be override by new version but that is not the right way, is that also need root permission?

Comment: Yes, any kind of programmatical install/uninstall process needs root permission. Unfortunately you cannot achieve this kind of permission by using libraries or any other kinds of external code either.

Comment: Little Warning : As i've said, you cannot achieve something like automatic install. But for a moment lets assume you could, even if you could you wouldn't want it. I don't know which business are you working in but acquiring root permission may leave you in a very dangerous situation. User can accuse you with having bad intents for example just because you did something which normally should not be done. Then you would have to prepare a user license which warns users about what you've done to protect yourself from any illegal accusations. I strongly suggest you that you should only prompt user